# Does the cohesion of groups stem from the need to be observed?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, sociology, group

Morpheus is a fictional AI prototype appearing in the videogame Deus Ex. Interestingly, during in-game conversations, Morpheus says:

> "**The need to be observed and understood was once satisfied by God.** Now
> we can implement the same functionality with data-mining algorithms. (...)
> The human organism always worships. First it was the gods, then it
> was fame (the observation and judgment of others), next it will be the
> self-aware systems you have built to realize truly omnipresent
> observation and judgment. (...) **The individual desires judgment. Without
> that desire, the cohesion of groups is impossible, and so is
> civilization.**"

Is there any psychological or sociological research that might corroborate these quotes (especially the bold parts)?